# Python : Running function in thread does not modify current_thread()

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm currently trying to figure out how threads work in python.

I have the following code:

```
def func1(arg1, arg2):

    print current_thread()
    ....

class class1:

    def __init__():
        ....

    def func_call():
        print current_thread()
        t1 = threading.Thread(func1(arg1, arg2))
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
```

What I noticed is that both prints output the same thing. Why is the thread not changing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're executing the function instead of passing it. Try this instead:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = func1, args = (arg1, arg2))
```

Answer (score 8):

You are calling the function before it is given to the `Thread` constructor.
Also, you are giving it as the wrong argument (the first positional argument to the Thread constructor is the `group`). Assuming `func1` returns `None` what you are doing is equivalent to calling `threading.Thread(None)` or `threading.Thread()`.
This is explained in more detail in the [threading docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

To make your code work try this:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=func1, args=(arg1, arg2))
t1.start()
t1.join()
```