# python multithread not working in my code?

Tags: python

```
from threading import Thread

def multithread():
    t1= Thread(target = producer)
    t1.run()

    t2 = Thread(target = consumer)
    t2.run()

def producer():
    print "current thread id is {0}".format(Thread.name)

def consumer():
    print "current thread id is {0}".format(Thread.name)
```

running result shows me that they are in the same thread ?? why ? any wrong in my code ?

```
current thread id is <property object at 0x7fc7839acf18>
current thread id is <property object at 0x7fc7839acf18>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add this at the end of the file

```
print Thread.name
```

you will see that you asking name from class that you imported from module threading, not from objects that you created.

```
from threading import Thread

def multithread():
    t1= Thread(target = producer)
    print t1.name
    t1.run()

    t2 = Thread(target = consumer)
    print t2.name
    t2.run()

def producer():
    print "current thread id is {0}".format(Thread.name)

def consumer():
    print "current thread id is {0}".format(Thread.name)

Thread-1
current thread id is <property object at 0x7f10752a45d0>
Thread-2
current thread id is <property object at 0x7f10752a45d0>
```

Now we got real names of your threads.

**Edit:**
I got it. You called run() method which just run target function in main thread. To launch function in new thread you must call method start().

```
from threading import Thread, current_thread

def multithread():
    t1= Thread(target = producer)
    t2 = Thread(target = consumer)

    for t in [t1, t2]:
        t.start()

    for t in [t1, t2]:
        t.join()

def producer():
    print "current thread id is {0}".format(current_thread())

def consumer():
    print "current thread id is {0}".format(current_thread())


multithread()
```

And output will be something like this

```
current thread id is <Thread(Thread-1, started 139800907732736)>
current thread id is <Thread(Thread-2, started 139800899340032)>
```

Comment: that doesn't make sense, how could I know that procedure and consumer are in the different thread ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import current_thread
...
def producer():
    print "current thread id is {0}".format(current_thread())

...etc
```

Reference: [Python : Running function in thread does not modify current_thread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460677/python-running-function-in-thread-does-not-modify-current-thread)

Comment: yes, they are in the same thead, main thread.... why procedure and consumer in the same/main thread...? that is my question

Comment: @liuzhidong, check other answer.